# SQL get field from row with max / min field

Tags: mysql, sql

So there is school project and I completely stuck on last step.
There's my code:

```
SELECT Consumidor.numero, Soma.soma
FROM Consumidor
JOIN
  (SELECT compra.consumidor, SUM(Eco.eco*compra.quantidade) as soma
   FROM compra
   JOIN
    (SELECT composto.produto, composto.prodMarca, Produto.nome, 
    sum(Elemento.pegadaEcologica * composto.percentagem/100) AS eco
    FROM composto
    JOIN Produto
    ON composto.produto = Produto.codigo
    AND composto.prodMarca = Produto.marca 
    JOIN Elemento
    ON composto.elemento = Elemento.codigo
    GROUP BY composto.produto, composto.prodMarca) Eco
   ON compra.produto = Eco.produto AND compra.prodMarca = Eco.prodMarca
   GROUP BY compra.consumidor) Soma
ON Consumidor.numero = Soma.Consumidor
```

So now I have table like:

```
Consumidor.number Soma.soma 
123               90
456               70
789               70
```

Expected result should be `Consumidor.number` (-s) where `Soma.soma` is min.

I.e. for this table result should be:

```
Consumidor.number
456     
789
```

There's original schema for all tables used in this query:

```
Consumidor (PK numero, email, sexo, nascimento)
Elemento (PK codigo, nome, pegadaEcologica, saude)
Produto (PK codigo, FK PK Marca.numero marca, nome, tipo, comercioJusto)
compra (FK PK Produto.codigo produto, FK PK Produto.marca prodMarca, Consumidor.numero, quantidade)
composto (FK PK Produto.codigo produto, FK PK Produto.marca prodMarca, FK PK Elemento.codigo elemento, percentagem)
```

Update.
I didnt stuck with solution - there is solution:

```
SELECT Consumidor.numero, Soma.soma
FROM Consumidor
JOIN
  (SELECT compra.consumidor, SUM(Eco.eco*compra.quantidade) as soma
   FROM compra
   JOIN
    (SELECT composto.produto, composto.prodMarca, Produto.nome, 
    sum(Elemento.pegadaEcologica * composto.percentagem/100) AS eco
    FROM composto
    JOIN Produto
    ON composto.produto = Produto.codigo
    AND composto.prodMarca = Produto.marca 
    JOIN Elemento
    ON composto.elemento = Elemento.codigo
    GROUP BY composto.produto, composto.prodMarca) Eco
   ON compra.produto = Eco.produto AND compra.prodMarca = Eco.prodMarca
   GROUP BY compra.consumidor) Soma
ON Consumidor.numero = Soma.Consumidor
WHERE Soma.soma <= ALL
  (SELECT SUM(Eco.eco*compra.quantidade) as soma
   FROM compra
   JOIN
    (SELECT composto.produto, composto.prodMarca, Produto.nome, 
    sum(Elemento.pegadaEcologica * composto.percentagem/100) AS eco
    FROM composto
    JOIN Produto
    ON composto.produto = Produto.codigo
    AND composto.prodMarca = Produto.marca 
    JOIN Elemento
    ON composto.elemento = Elemento.codigo
    GROUP BY composto.produto, composto.prodMarca) Eco
   ON compra.produto = Eco.produto AND compra.prodMarca = Eco.prodMarca
   GROUP BY compra.consumidor)
```

Simply put whole Soma query onto WHERE clause. With this im getting expected resault. But this looks so ugly and im looking for some more elegant way.

P.S. Don't throw tomatoes - following project statement I'm not able to use sub-queries in `FROM` clause, but if there are some observations about whole my code I will appreciate.

Comment: You realize that your current `from` clause contains subselects, right?

Comment: Please include some sample input and output data.

Comment: @Jacobm001 i mean there is not allowed selects like from(select  ....), all my subselects now inside a
 join clause

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what are you interested in? I ve included output table of my current code and expected output after some operation that is question about

Comment: The original table schema would help greatly.

Comment: You have a doubly nested query in there and I can't decompose the problem in my mind.  You need to understand that we don't have your data.

Comment: Added table schema

Comment: please put your sample data

Comment: there is no `composto.produto`, please put your real scheme, sample data and expected result

Comment: @ColourDalnet why sample data is needed? I mean it can be completely anything.. Question is about how to get a row with a field with minimum value. BTW I've updated a quastion, maybe now  it's more clearly..

Comment: Can you solved formula 2x+4y/2z-4xy without knowing x,y,z? The result must be 10, but my answer is 20. The problem is the formula. Please tell me the right formula, it can be anything

Comment: @ColourDalnet I dont need exact x,y,z to make a formula... that is named formula because it gives some expected result with any  x,y,z. x+y+z will always be x+y+z, it can be 10, 20 depends on x,y,z numbers.

Comment: exactly, your output can be anything depends on your input, but it is your problem. I don't really care either if you didnt give exact input (sample). The one who asking help here is you.

Comment: @ColourDalnet ok.. maybe i sould change a question. Is it possible to beautify my second example? Or is it possimpe somehow include created Soma alias to WHERE or HAVING clause?

Comment: you better post your data here http://sqlfiddle.com and link the fiddle in question, ppls will help you faster if you really pay attention with peoples commented here.

Comment: The problem is the big Soma join.  Can you provide the project at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?  Once you've done that- provide the link and tell us what your expected output is.

Answer (score -1):

So there is no really other way to solve it

```
SELECT Consumidor.numero
FROM compra
JOIN Consumidor
ON compra.consumidor = Consumidor.numero
JOIN
    (SELECT composto.produto, composto.prodMarca, Produto.nome, 
     sum(Elemento.pegadaEcologica * composto.percentagem/100) AS eco
     FROM composto
     JOIN Produto
     ON composto.produto = Produto.codigo
     AND composto.prodMarca = Produto.marca 
     JOIN Elemento
     ON composto.elemento = Elemento.codigo
     GROUP BY composto.produto, composto.prodMarca) Eco
ON compra.produto = Eco.produto AND compra.prodMarca = Eco.prodMarca
GROUP BY compra.consumidor
HAVING SUM(Eco.eco*compra.quantidade)<= ALL
    (SELECT SUM(Eco.eco*compra.quantidade)
     FROM compra
     JOIN Consumidor
     ON compra.consumidor = Consumidor.numero
     LEFT JOIN Dependente
     ON Dependente.consumidor = Consumidor.numero
     JOIN
        (SELECT composto.produto, composto.prodMarca, Produto.nome, 
         sum(Elemento.pegadaEcologica * composto.percentagem/100) AS eco
         FROM composto
         JOIN Produto
         ON composto.produto = Produto.codigo
         AND composto.prodMarca = Produto.marca 
         JOIN Elemento
         ON composto.elemento = Elemento.codigo
         GROUP BY composto.produto, composto.prodMarca) Eco
     ON compra.produto = Eco.produto
     AND compra.prodMarca = Eco.prodMarca
     GROUP BY compra.consumidor);
```

To get field with minimum value from current table you have to query this whole table in HAVING clause (check in which group SUM of compras less or equal of SUM of compras in ALL groups in current table).
It can be marked as duplicate of any likely question.